# Downcasting with dynamic_cast and polymorphic classes not working

Tags: c++

I am having several problems trying to downcast a class into another one to access an specific method of that class. This is my current scheme of classes:

GameObject class:

```
class GameObject
{
...
}
```

Enemy class:

```
#include "../GameObject.h"

class Enemy : public GameObject
{
Enemy(Type type);
virtual ~Enemy();
virtual int receiveDamage(int attack_points);
virtual void levelUp() = 0;
...
protected:
char *name_;
int level_;
int health_;
int max_health_;
int attack_;
int armor_;
}
```

SmallGoblin class:

```
#include "../Enemy.h"

class SmallGoblin : public Enemy
{
public:
SmallGoblin();
~SmallGoblin();

void levelUp();
}
```

In my code, I try to do this and a std::bad_cast exception is thrown every time.

```
class Player : GameObject
{
...
virtual void attack(GameObject &enemy)
{
try
    {
        Enemy &e = dynamic_cast<Enemy&>(enemy);
        e.receiveDamage(attack_points_);
    }
    catch(const std::bad_cast& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        std::cerr << "This object is not of type Enemy\n";
    }
}
...
}
```

(enemy is a reference to a GameObject object, however I know it's actually a SmallGoblin object).

In other part my code I have anoother class (Door) which extends the GameObject class and the downcasting works (however, I have to use static_cast instead dynamic_cast I don't know why).

Comment: Could you provide an SSCCE?

Comment: I'll update the question with my real code.

Comment: If you have to use `static_cast`, you're probably getting undefined behaviour.

Comment: So does `GameObject` have any virtual functions?

Comment: @sftrabbit I know, but dynamic_casting isn't working however :/

Comment: You can cast a `GameObject &` to a `SmallGoblin &` directly: `static_cast<SmallGoblin &>(enemy)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Only if the `GameObject` is actually a `SmallGoblin`. Presumably, the game has other enemy types in it, hense the `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The OP says "however I know it's actually a `SmalLGoblin` object". I'm assuming the OP isn't lying to us.

Comment: @KerrekSB: for **this particular example**, yes, but I would assume that in the larger scope of the project, the OP is not going to focus on just `SmallGoblin` objects.

Comment: I just love reading you, guys, talking about `Small Goblins`. Sounds exquisitely nerdy.

Comment: @Puyover: why not just make `attack()` take an `Enemy&` as input to begin with? Then you don't have to worry about casting. Or do you plan on allowing players to attack `Door`s as well, for instance?  If so, then `receiveDamage()` should be moved to `GameObject()` itself, or else `attack()` should be overloaded for different types of input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The flow the code is working, is that the player checks collisions with every GameObject around him, and then a switch statement is executed to determine which type of GameObject we have. So I will have to downcast after all...

Comment: @Puyover: If you have to manually check the object's type and then cast it, then you are not utilizing polymorphism correctly. If the player collides with an object, let the collided object decide what to do with the collision (damage, no-op, etc). Make the decision function virtual in `GameObject` so objects can override it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention in one of your comments that you are storing `std::vector<GameObject>`.  Unfortunately, this will cause your `GameObject` objects to be [sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).  A great description can be found here: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

> "Slicing" is where you assign an object of a derived class to an instance of a base class, thereby losing part of the information - some of it is "sliced" away.

To solve this problem, you need to  store a vector of pointers.  You have some choices here, if you're using C++11.  You can store either:

```
std::vector<GameObject*> badGameObjects;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>> uGameObjects;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>> sGameObjects;
```

All of these options will ensure that slicing doesn't happen because the vector is just storing pointers.  Storing naked pointers is the least desirable option because you will have to manage the memory yourself and can be a source of memory leaks.  The use of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` will depend on how you need to use the objects.

Comment: Thank you for formalizing the answer. I'll change it as I said before :P

Answer (score 2):

If `dynamic_cast` is failing, then `enemy` is not actually a valid `Enemy` instance, so double-check how you are managing that reference.

The following works fine for me when I try it:

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual ~GameObject(){}
};

enum Type {goblin};

class Enemy : public GameObject
{
public:
    Enemy(Type type) : type_(type) {}
    virtual ~Enemy() {}
    virtual int receiveDamage(int attack_points) {}
    virtual void levelUp() = 0;
protected:
    Type type_;
    //...
};

class SmallGoblin : public Enemy
{
public:
    SmallGoblin() : Enemy(goblin) {}
    ~SmallGoblin() {}

    void levelUp() {}
};

class Player : GameObject
{
public:
    int attack_points_;

    virtual void attack(GameObject &enemy)
    {
        try
        {
            Enemy &e = dynamic_cast<Enemy&>(enemy);
            e.receiveDamage(attack_points_);
        }
        catch(const std::bad_cast& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
            std::cerr << "This object is not of type Enemy\n";
        }
    }
};
```

.

```
Player p;
SmallGoblin goblin;
p.attack(goblin);
```

BTW, I would use `dynamic_cast` with pointers instead, to avoid the unnecessary overhead of using exceptions:

```
virtual void attack(GameObject &enemy)
{
    Enemy *e = dynamic_cast<Enemy*>(&enemy);
    if (e)
        e->receiveDamage(attack_points_);
    else
        std::cerr << "This object is not of type Enemy\n";
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if every time I get a GameObject is through a reference to it? Because all my GameObject are stored in an std::vector and in the question's case the reference is passed to 3 function through GameObject&. I don't know if maybe the type may be "lost" in the process...

Comment: @Puyover I suspect that slicing is the source of your problems.  If you're using a std::vector<GameObject> then you are suffering from slicing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: You will need to store pointers to `GameObject`s.  Better still store smart pointers to `GameObject` such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` depending on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

`dynamic_cast` shouldn't be used for downcasting, I'm pretty sure `static_cast` does the job. `dynamic_cast` is used for "upcasting" instead.

Comment: But upcasting is a implicit operation. There is no need to use explicit casting like dynamic_cast to achieve it...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast

I'm pretty sure it's not implicit in this example.

Comment: Upcasting occurs implicitly when the derivation is public.